# Stuck on ROG screen after Nividia update, can't enter terminal mode

Tags: command-line

I don't know what to do. It was was working fine until I switched the additional devices to Nividia propriety and now it's stuck on the ROG screen. I can't enter terminal mode with clicking CTRL + ALT + F1 or F3.

Comment: What is "the ROG screen"?

Comment: @waltinator the logo screen Republic of Gamers.